# JavaScript not comparing the parameter value passed

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button

I have following html -

```
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton1" 
onclick="javascript:radioWithText('one')" checked="checked" />OneRadio<br/>
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" 
onclick="javascript:radioWithText('two')" unchecked />TwoRadio
<br/>
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" 
onclick="javascript:radioWithText('three')" unchecked />ThreeRadio
<br/>
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" 
onclick="javascript:radioWithText('four')" unchecked />FourRadio
```

and also this

```
<span id="one" name="one" width="5px" style="background-color:#fff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span id="two" name="one" width="5px" style="background-color:#fff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span id="three" name="one" width="5px" style="background-color:#fff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<span id="four" name="one" width="5px" style="background-color:#fff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

This produces a 4 small width square in white on my background color of green. Those four square are shown and i want to change their color off-course background to be red when particular radio button is selected. For that shake i pass a paramter with javascript `javascript:radioWithText('one')`. As you can see the function is passed a parameter ok! Next is to do javascript with the function i called.

```
function radioWithText(d) {
    alert(d);
    if (d.val=='one')
    {
        var one = document.getElementById('one');
        //one.checked = true;
        one.style.background="red";
    }
}
```

You can see probably when the radio button is checked it alert the value passed (the button which is selected). In alert it show `"one"` `"two"` `"three"` `"four"` while the same value that is when first radio button is placed passes `"one"` when compared it not comparing what may be the reason? help me out!
Desperately a silly mistake thanks in advance

Comment: There’s no need to put `javascript:` in inline event handlers.

Comment: Why are you alerting `d` but comparing `d.val`? If `d` is a string, you should be comparing `d`; if it is a form element, you want to compare `d.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `javascript:` from the inline events:

```
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton1" 
onclick="radioWithText('one')" checked="checked" />OneRadio<br/>
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" 
onclick="radioWithText('two')" unchecked />TwoRadio
<br/>
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" 
onclick="radioWithText('three')" unchecked />ThreeRadio
<br/>
<input type="Radio" name="radio2text" value="Radiobutton2" 
onclick="radioWithText('four')" unchecked />FourRadio
```

Secondly, you're passing a string to your function, so there is no `.val` property. Remove that:

```
function radioWithText(d) {
    alert(d);
    if (d == 'one')
    {
        var one = document.getElementById('one');
        //one.checked = true;
        one.style.background="red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.val`. Your parameter is a string, there is no `.val`

```
function radioWithText(d) {
    alert(d);
    if (d == 'one')
    {
        var one = document.getElementById('one');
        //one.checked = true;
        one.style.background="red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `d` holds the value you need to compare. It does not have a property named `val`.

The comparison line should be:

```
if (d === 'one')
```

Answer (score 0):

No Val needed.

```
function radioWithText(d) {
    alert(d);
    if (d == 'one')
    {
        var one = document.getElementById('one');
        //one.checked = true;
        one.style.background="red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `d.val`

The `d` variable is equal to `'one'`.

```
function radioWithText(d) {
alert(d);
if (d=='one')
{
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    //one.checked = true;
    one.style.background="red";
    }
}
```

Also, no need for the `javascript:` in your `onclick` events. `onclick` maps directly to javascript, unlike `a` elements.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/agrothe/rWvtR/)